# Run manage.py with custom database configuration

Tags: django

My use case involves running `python manage.py migrate` with `DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1` (since I use [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)). However, when the application is uploaded and is serving, the database URL needs to change to an actual remote URL.

Right now, I upload a special `settings.py` file that contains the localhost URL when I wish to run the migration command. When I deploy to cloud, I make sure to overwrite that file with a new one (which is essentially the entire file except the database URL is my remote db URL) and then upload it.

Is there a better way to achieve this? Something like `python manage.py --database_url=127.0.0.1 migrate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jq to modify a JSON file I read values from (`DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1`), then overwrote the new JSON file once I was done running migrations with the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try making a separate file, let's say **local_settings.py**, in the **settings.py** directory. In that file copy the **ALLOWED_HOSTS =["your IP"]**.
Then in your settings.py import it as form **try: .local_settings import * except: pass**
But keep the **ALLOWED_HOSTS=[ ]** in your **settings.py** as it is.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't...understand your answer. Why would ALLOWED_HOSTS help? As per my understanding, that variable controls what sites your Django app is allowed to serve.